# ionic 2 - keep keyboard open when clicking send button

Tags: angular, keyboard, ionic2, focus, textarea

the keyboard in ionic opens when an input/textarea field become focused(?).

But when I click on a send button, the keyboard disappears.

even when I call the keyboard.show() method of the keyboard plugin, it disappears first, then reappears.

Is there a solution to that?

```
<textarea id="chat-text-area></textarea>

sendMessage() {
    if(window.cordova){
        this.keyboard.show()
    }
    if(this.form.valid){
        this.service.post(this.form.value).subscribe(res=>{
            document.getElementById('chat-text-area').focus()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

add this to your send button:

```
(mousedown)="$event.preventDefault(); sendMessage($event)"
```

i hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! This is still working as of Ionic 5/6. The only thing to keep in mind is that if the page is showing the `ion-loading` for example the focus will still be lost (using a spinner icon in the button would give you a similar UX and the keyboard would remain visible).

Answer (score 1):

Can you inject your logic in hide event?

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);

function keyboardHideHandler(e){
    if (something) // put your condition here
        e.preventDefault();
}
```